# Makefile process all files in one directory, output to another.

Tags: makefile

How do I set up a Makefile to process all files in one directory, redirecting output to another (one output file per input file)? I have:

```
INPUTS := $(wildcard ./input/*.txt)
OUTPUTS := $(patsubst %.out,%.txt,$(wildcard ./input/*.txt))

$(OUTPUTS): $(INPUTS)
    python process.py $@ > ./output/${@:%.txt=%.out}
```

... but it keeps regenerating files in ./output that are already there.

Comment: You get what you asked for: the third line tells make that **each** output file depends on **all** input files. Adding one new input file causes all output files to be regenerated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
INPUTS := $(wildcard ./input/*.txt)

# Create a list of all the output files you want to generate
OUTPUTS := $(patsubst ./input/%.txt,./output/%.out,$(INPUTS))

# The default is to build all the OUTPUTS files
all: $(OUTPUTS)

# Tell make how to build a single output file
./output/%.out : ./input/%.txt
        python process.py $< > $@
```